# How to embbed data in d3 script?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm looking at this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

I want to embed the json data inside the script as opposed to using d3's internal function. I tried a variety of things like assigning the data to a var etc. but it doesn't seem to work.

How do you do this, for this example in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you would assign the contents of the JSON to a variable, like so:

```
var json = {...};
```

In this case in particular, have a look [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/10536946).

Comment: Eh, I was putting the json data inside an array, messed things up. Thanks.